# Attach a finished drawing event to the Flotr or Flotr2

Tags: flotr2, flotr

I'm using the Flotr2 lib:
https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2

I have been searching everywhere to just understand how to add a callback or an event handler which gets triggered when the Flotr graph is actually finished with its drawing.

My graph draws okay with small or mid size data but when I use a larger set of data, the graph takes much longer to draw. While it's trying to draw, the graph container is blank so I would like to show a loading spinner while it's trying to draw and hide this spinner when the graph is actually finished with its drawing.

So my question is how to know when the graph has really completed its drawing?

Could someone please point me to the right direction or provide with some code sample.
Any help would be much much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I've only tried my answer with smallish data sets that I have handy. You might want to show your code so people know what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the call to `Flotr.draw` in another function, and just put your spinner code inside the calling function.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // show the spinner here

    Flotr.draw(
        document.getElementById("chart"),
        data,
        options
    );

    // hide the spinner here
}
```

I've used `windows.onload` as a wrapper, but you could also use a custom function that you call explicitly.